# NHibernate: combine fluent configuraiton with attribute-based configuration

Tags: nhibernate

In Entity Framework it is possible to combine fluent configuration with attribute-based configuration.

As in NHibernate both configuration approaches are different projects I guess they're not combineable, however, maybe I'm misunderstood.

Is it possible to combine both approaches in NHibernate or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to choose what type of configuration (or mapping) you want to do. [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/), `Xml`, `Attributies`. You do not need to create your configuration in a separated project, but it is a good pratice to keep the single responsability for each part of your code. I really recommend you mapping using the fluent NHibernate.

This article show each type of mapping:
http://www.davesquared.net/2008/09/nhibernate-mappings-using-xml.html